# Why is x = x+1 slower than x += 1?

Tags: php, performance, increment

I am a PHP programmer. I always prefer to use `x += 1;` instead of `x = x + 1;`.

But still I don't understand why people say execution of `x += 1;` is faster than `x = x + 1;`.

(editor's note: This question didn't originally specify PHP, hence the comments and answers talking about C++ compilers.)

Comment: Who told you there's a performance difference?

Comment: It depends on compiler

Comment: A difference, *if any*, depends on *language* (many languages treat them as synonyms, but bot all) - and the *implementation* of such..

Comment: If this is C++ then all bets are off. You can overload the operators to do whatever the hell you want - including to troll the reader.

Comment: @Amit, In many thread related with performance & best practices of programming.

Comment: @Purushottam Can you provide a link to one of the many threads?

Comment: You do not need to care about this. Seriously. Even if one variant is quicker, you cannot count on it being so in future versions of the language optimisations are added to it. More importantly, the difference, if any, is tiny. There is no point trying to optimise your code to take advantage of this kind of difference. Unless you are doing it millions of times in a loop, any difference will be completely invisible. Optimise the real bottlenecks in your code first before you stop to think about the micro-optimisations like this.

Answer (score 4):

http://3v4l.org/GjPvL/vld#tabs will show you the answer.

`$x += 1;` is interpreted as ASSIGN_ADD

`$x = $x + 1;` has a separate add and assign operation and uses a temporary variable.

The less opcode, the faster it will run(in most cases).

Note that if you enable opcache with code optimization, `$x = $x + 1;` will be optimized to use ASSIGN_ADD.

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is what is called [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). This is a convenience for developers. The two statements should have identical results in terms of logic and performance.

Comment: But what if x is an object?

Comment: If the language and developers are not doing anything too fishy, `x += y` and `x = x + y` should do the same thing. I am sure there are languages where it is possible to violate this.

Answer (score 1):

Decent compilers will pick up that

```
x = x +1
x += 1
x++
```

to be the same and in the end compile the same code, thus providing no difference.

Comment: But what if x is an object?

Comment: @ikegami if x is an object, and whoever implemented it made it so that `x = x+1` results in a different value in x than `x += 1`, while both being "legal operations", then: A. I'd feel comfortable claiming it's a horrifying design decision. B. It's no longer a performance issue, so irrelevant for the question. If the result is identical, and performance is not then I'd feel comfortable saying there's an implementation flaw.